# Improving / upscaling old VHS video footage

Tags: vhs, footage

i've recorded an old video tape via USB grabber - it has a resoution of 720x576 pixels.
What i want to do now is:

- enhancing quality by AI-resizing to 4K (maybe using Topaz AI 4 or a cheaper method)
- apply some video stabilization as the footage is pretty shaky
- apply frame interpolation by using Flowframes for smoother video

In what order should i do it? Can you recommend software for those tasks? I was thinking about using Videodub and the Deshaker plugin - or maybe Adobe premiere?

Thanks